# Reportlab Canvas Image Not Showing

Tags: python, reportlab

**Background**

I am writing some code to set up a shared document "template" [ common header and footer ] in ReportLab using a `SimpleDocTemplate` ( `reportlab.platypus.SimpleDocTemplate` ). The code snippet below is a function that is to be passed into the `SimpleDocTemplate` `build(...)` method as the value of either the `onFirstPage` or `onLaterPages` parameter.

```
def setup_header_and_footer(canvas, doc):
    """
    ...edited out...
    """
    canvas.line(0 * mm, 174 * mm, 297 * mm, 174 * mm)
    logo_filename = settings.STATIC_ROOT + os.sep + "images/huqas_logo.jpg"
    canvas.drawImage(logo_filename, 20 * mm, 45 * mm)

    canvas.drawRightString(287 * mm, 200 * mm, "<edited out>")
    canvas.drawString(20 * mm, 15 * mm, "Generated on %s" % datetime.now().strftime("%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p"))
    canvas.line(0 * mm, 20 * mm, 297 * mm, 20 * mm)
```

**Further Information**

- The page / canvas has been set up with A4 landscape dimensions
- I have confirmed that logo_filename is a valid path, and that the image exists at that location in the filesystem
- Reportlab does not raise any exception

**The Problem**

- My lines and strings render OK, but the image is not visible in the resulting PDFs

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356413/draw-images-with-canvas-and-use-simpledoctemplate) but I still do not understand why the canvas would "behave" when calling eg `canvas.line(0 * mm, 174 * mm, 297 * mm, 174 * mm)` but fail when calling `canvas.drawImage("file name", 20 * mm, 45 * mm)`. I have also scoured the documentation to no avail. What am I missing?

**Update**

Changing from `canvas.drawImage(logo_filename, 20 * mm, 45 * mm)` to `canvas.drawInlineImage(logo_filename, 20 * mm, 45 * mm)` appears to "fix" the issue [ without changing any other line of code ]. I am still puzzled as to why `drawImage` did not work.

Comment: You're not getting any errors/warnings at all when you execute this function?

Comment: When this function is executed [ passed into a build(...) call on a SimpleDocTemplate instance ] it does not give any errors. All the lines and strings render correctly, including the "bottom line" that is defined in the last statement.

Comment: ReportLab uses [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) for reading bitmaps. Test if your PIL package can read the JPEG correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The documentation suggests that JPEG images are read by reportlab natively, with or without PIL. Even so, I have confirmed that the PIL can read this JPG correctly. I have also found that using "drawInlineImage" instead of "drawImage" works [ with nothing else changed in the code ]. I will edit the question with the new information, but keep it open since I still do not understand why drawImage is failing in this case ( but working in simple console tests )

Comment: You are right about ReportLab native JPEG support. Good you found a workaround.